# Get list of VMS in Azure recovery vault

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a way to list all the VMS listed in recovery vault using powershell?

I've been hunting around online and have only seen commands to manage virtual machines but not list them. I'm trying to list all the protected VMS and the last backup date. If it's possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for your help, I'll give that a go later, could you just give me an idea what a container is in this context and what its role here? Thanks

Comment: Hi, based on my knowledge, container same as a folder, we backup Azure VMs to that folder, then different VMs' backup store in different sub-folders. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Jason I'm getting the error cannot convert 'system object []' to type Microsoft.azure.commands.recoveryservices.backup.cmdlets.models.containerbase .. however when I do a $nameContainer it shows all VMS and state but not the last backup date

Comment: Please try to add `-FriendlyName "vmname"`, and try angain

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT excellent thanks Jason. I tried your code on my home subscription and it works a treat .. thanks 

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT hi jay that works for individual machines but I was hoping to capture every machine in the recovery vault .. sorry to be a pain 

Comment: We can use `foreach` to list Azure VMs in Azure backup vault, I have update my answer, please check it, Also if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to list all the protected VMS and the last backup date

We can use PowerShell to list **VMs** in the recovery service vault and the **latest recovery point**, like this:

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "jasonbackup" -ResourceGroupName "backup" | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext

$nameContainer = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName "jasonvm"

Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $nameContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM" | select ContainerName,LatestRecoveryPoint
```

[image]

My VMs name are `jasonvm` and `jasonvm2`.

=============================================
**Update**:

If we have many VMs, we can use `Foreach` to list Azure VM `Name` and `LatestRecoveryPoint`, we can use this script:

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "jasonbackup" -ResourceGroupName "backup" | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext

$fnames = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" | select  -ExpandProperty friendlyname

 foreach ($name in $fnames)
 {
 $nameContainer = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName $name
 Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $nameContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM" | select ContainerName,LatestRecoveryPoint
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perfect .. worked a treat .. thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Saved me from a restless weekend pulling my hair out, great help thank you 

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with the `Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext` command (Powershell 6.0 with AZ Module).
it seems it will be deprecated to set the context as suggested here:
[KB MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-afs-automation#fetch-the-vault-id)

just add the `-vaultID` value to the Jason's command, eg:

```
$vaultID = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "backup" -Name "jasonbackup" | select -ExpandProperty ID
fnames = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -VaultId $vaultID | select  -ExpandProperty friendlyname
```